# Belkin Surf N300 Router - 2nd hand - Default Gateway not available

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

Hi I got a 2nd hand belkin router but after installing with the CD, I am able to connect to the internet.  I have the ssid and password from the original owner.  I continually get a

> Default Gate way not available.

error

**Actions tried:**

- Restarting router
- restarting and resetting router
- restarting computer
- disable and enable router
- cmd - run as administrator....

This is so frustrating.

Comment: Can we have more details? What is the model number of the router? How is your router *supposed* to be able to reach the internet? Who is your ISP? Can you log into your router and view your settings?

Comment: What do you mean by "resetting router"?

Comment: Default gateway not awailable means that your PC and the router are not configured on the same network. Your PC is trying to solve this by using a default route, which has not been set.